# How to create TRON transaction?

Tags: blockchain, tron

I installed **Tronbox** and want to deploy smart contract. But before that, I want to create a transaction for which I have private key and address. So, I installed **tron-api-cli**, followed instruction from link https://www.npmjs.com/package/tron-api-cli. But I am not getting how to create transaction in command line. Can somebody help? 
Even the **tron-api-cli** installation is completed, **tron-api-cli** command gives error:

> tron-api-cli: command not found

Answer (score 0):

The package is kind of misnamed. It's not a Command Line Interface (CLI), it's a client that you can use inside a Javascript application.

To create a transaction in JS, you use the [TransactionFactory](https://github.com/trxplorer/tron-api-cli/blob/master/src/transaction/Factory.js). For example, see the method sendTRX from [AccountCLI class](https://github.com/trxplorer/tron-api-cli/blob/master/src/AccountCli.js):

```
sendTRX(toAddress,amount,node){
    pKeyRequired(this.pkey)
    let tx = TransactionFactory.createTx(TronProtocol.Transaction.Contract.ContractType.TRANSFERCONTRACT,{owner:this.address,to:toAddress,amount})
    return this.blockCli.addRef(tx).then((txWithRef)=>{
        let transactionString = this.sign(txWithRef,this.pkey)
        return axios.post(`${this.endpoint}${API_TRON_BROADCAST}`,{payload:transactionString,node}).then((res)=>{return res.data})            
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

**TronWallet SDK**

You can run the following command to install the Tron in your project.

```
PM> Install-Package TronWallet
```

**Configuration**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace ConsoleApp1;

using Tron;

public record TronRecord(IServiceProvider ServiceProvider, ITronClient? TronClient, IOptions<TronNetOptions>? Options);

public static class TronServiceExtension {
    private static IServiceProvider AddTron() {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddTronNet(x => {
            x.Network = TronNetwork.MainNet;
            x.Channel = new GrpcChannelOption { Host = "grpc.trongrid.io", Port = 50051 };
            x.SolidityChannel = new GrpcChannelOption { Host = "grpc.trongrid.io", Port = 50052 };
            x.ApiKey = "80a8b20f-a917-43a9-a2f1-809fe6eec0d6";
        });
        services.AddLogging();
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public static TronRecord GetRecord() {
        var provider = AddTron();
        var client = provider.GetService<ITronClient>();
        var options = provider.GetService<IOptions<TronNetOptions>>();

        return new TronRecord(provider, client, options);
    }
}
```

**Sample 1: Generate Address Offline**

```
namespace ConsoleApp1;

using Tron;

internal class Program {    
    private static void Main() {
        var tronEcKey = TronECKey.GenerateKey(TronNetwork.MainNet);
        var privateKey = tronEcKey.GetPrivateKey();
        var address = tronEcKey.GetPublicAddress();

        Console.WriteLine($"{privateKey}\t{address}");
    }
}
```

**Sample 2: Transfer TRX/USDT and account permission update**

```
namespace ConsoleApp1;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using Tron;
using Tron.Accounts;
using Tron.Contracts;

internal class Program {
    private static async Task Main() {
        var privateKey = "your private key here.";
        var toAddress = "your receive address here.";
        var amount = 1_000_000L;

        //transfer out trx
        var result = await TrxTransferAsync(privateKey, toAddress, amount);
        Console.WriteLine(result.TransactionId);

        //transfer out usdt
        var decimalAmount = new decimal(1);
        var transactionId = await EtherTransferAsync(privateKey, toAddress, decimalAmount, null);
        Console.WriteLine(transactionId);

        //Account permission update
        var ownerAddress = "your owner address here.";
        var r = await AccountPermissionUpdateAsync(privateKey, ownerAddress);
        Console.WriteLine(r.TransactionId);
    }


    private static async Task<dynamic> TrxTransferAsync(string privateKey, string to, long amount) {
        var record = TronServiceExtension.GetRecord();
        var transactionClient = record.TronClient?.GetTransaction();

        var account = new TronAccount(privateKey, TronNetwork.MainNet);

        var transactionExtension = await transactionClient?.CreateTransactionAsync(account.Address, to, amount)!;

        var transactionId = transactionExtension.Txid.ToStringUtf8();

        var transactionSigned = transactionClient.GetTransactionSign(transactionExtension.Transaction, privateKey);
        var returnObj = await transactionClient.BroadcastTransactionAsync(transactionSigned);

        return new { Result = returnObj.Result, Message = returnObj.Message?.ToStringUtf8(), TransactionId = transactionId };
    }

    private static async Task<string> EtherTransferAsync(string privateKey, string toAddress, decimal amount, string? memo) {
        const string contractAddress = "TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t";

        var record = TronServiceExtension.GetRecord();
        var contractClientFactory = record.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContractClientFactory>();
        var contractClient = contractClientFactory?.CreateClient(ContractProtocol.TRC20);

        var account = new TronAccount(privateKey, TronNetwork.MainNet);

        const long feeAmount = 60 * 1000000L;

        return await contractClient.TransferAsync(contractAddress, account, toAddress, amount, memo, feeAmount);
    }

    private static async Task<dynamic> AccountPermissionUpdateAsync(string privateKey, string ownerAddress) {
        var record = TronServiceExtension.GetRecord();
        var transactionClient = record.TronClient?.GetTransaction();
        var account = new TronAccount(privateKey, TronNetwork.MainNet);

        var transactionExtention = await transactionClient?.CreateAccountPermissionUpdateTransactionAsync(account.Address, ownerAddress)!;

        var transactionSigned = transactionClient.GetTransactionSign(transactionExtention.Transaction, privateKey);
        var returnObj = await transactionClient.BroadcastTransactionAsync(transactionSigned);

        return new { Result = returnObj.Result, Message = returnObj.Message?.ToStringUtf8(), TransactionId = transactionExtention.Transaction.GetTxid() };
    }
}
```